# Jquery plugin image scroller with previous and next image visible to side

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am looking for a jquery plugin that has a scrolling image effect where the previous and next images are still visible but smaller on either side of the current image/frame.

Similar to this one: http://www.eogallery.com/ but smoother with the side images centered

I know I have seen it before but I haven't been able to find it after extensive searches.

Anyone know a plugin like that?

Thanks, especially for leading me to the name of the effect "carousel"

I found what I think is the best example here: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-carousel-evolution/full_screen_preview/490018

Comment: Just modify that one - change the animation to an `ease-in-out` curve to smooth it, give the smaller `li`'s a class and put in the CSS for moving it down (e.g. `position: relative; top: 100px;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a plugin but you can see the the source:

http://www.roxon.in/scripts/tutorials/NavGallery_jQuery_Tutorial_01/index5.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this one:
http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel

The plugin has a lot of configuration and options